# The generic you in French

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

La construction suivante est assez commune :

> When you get there, you're told what to do, then they show you where you need to go.

Dans cette phrase, la personne à qui "you" fait référence n'existe pas en vrai - il s'agit du [Generic You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you).

Alors qu'en français, j'avoue que j'ai du mal parfois, parce que par instinct, je veux dire « tu/vous », mais il me semble que la façon correcte est plutôt « on ». Autrement dit, je suis sûr, que quelque chose de similaire doit exister, mais, je n'arrive pas à mettre le doigt dessus.

Concrètement, je me demande quelle phrase est plus correcte parmi les deux suivantes, et si je peux appliquer cette règle en général :

> Quand vous serez arrivé, ils vous dirons quoi faire, ensuite ils vous montreront par où il faut aller

ou

> Quand on sera arrivé, ils nous diront quoi faire, ensuite ils nous montreront par où il faut aller

Comment: Just as a note, you is derived from French vous and thou thine is from tu, tiens. I believe that the informal version lost favor in English because it takes more calories to pronounce, whereas in French the Vous takes more effort to enunciate, so the tu is very popular and Vous can sound poetic, reminiscent of voulte and avoue.

Comment: On [peut utiliser](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?45;s=3726743910;r=5;nat=;sol=1;) "tu" comme équivalent du *generic you* en français, mais c'est familier ou populaire.

Comment: @LifeinTheTrees: *you* is derived from [Old English *eow*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=you) and *thou* is derived from [Old English *þu*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=thou). They're similar to *vous* and *tu* because Old English and Latin shared a common ancestral language: Indo-European.

Comment: @PeterShor, No, The spelling, the sound, and the meaning of "you" comes from the French vous, that's why it was spelt, latinized, said, and employed the same way. England had multiple dialects and dominions at that time of the Norman invasion, so "Old English" is just Saxon. By old English we forget Frisian, Saxon, Norse, Celtic dialects and forms of you latinized ["juz and Iwwe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You) .  All these germanic norse celtic roots, spellings, sounds, and  uses were deprecated after about 1066 by Normal english. Also Thine is clearly French, not Germanic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs façons d'exprimer ça.

1. On utilise des formules impersonnelles qui permettent d'éviter d'utiliser un pronom pour la ou les personnes à qui *you* fait référence en anglais :

   > À l'arrivée, on explique ce qu'il faut faire puis on montre où il faut aller.
2. On peut utiliser le pronom *on*, dans son acception indéterminée :

   > Quand on arrive là, on nous explique ce qu'il faut faire puis on nous montre où on doit aller.
3. La deuxième personne du pluriel est aussi possible avec le même sens générique que l'anglais, mais c'est plutôt utilisé à l'écrit :

   > Quand vous arrivez là, on vous explique ce qu'il faut faire puis on vous montre où vous devez aller.

   Le tutoiement est aussi bien sûr possible, comme dans la réponse de @XouDo:

   > Quand tu arrives là, on t'explique[...]

Comment: La première phrase est formulée du point de ceux qui expliquent et non de ceux qui arrivent, ce qui ne me semble pas l'esprit de la phrase citée dans la question.

Answer (score 2):

Votre question semble indiquer que la formulation avec tu/vous n'est pas correcte pour ce cas. Je ne suis pas d'accord, cela peut tout à faire convenir et c'est parfaitement naturel en français :

> Quand tu arrives là-bas, on te dit quoi faire et on te dit où tu dois aller.

mais ça marche aussi avec *vous* (si on parle à quelqu'un de moins connu ou un groupe d'amis)

> Quand vous arrivez là-bas, on vous dit quoi faire et on vous montre où aller.

on peut l'utiliser sans le *on*, avec un *ils* indéfini :

> Quand tu arrives là-bas, ils te disent quoi faire et où tu dois aller.

On n'est pas obligé d'utiliser le présent (même si c'est le plus courant). Le futur fonctionne aussi, avec plusieurs formulations possibles :

> - Quand tu arriveras là-bas, on te dira quoi faire et te montrera où aller.
> - Quand tu seras là-bas, (...)
> - Une fois là-bas, (...)

Comment: *Quand tu arriveras là-bas* n'est pas une formule générique. Elle ne me semble pas correspondre à l'esprit de la phrase citée dans la question ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre je suis d'accord que *tu* n'es pas approprié dans ce contexte, mais il peut tout à fait être générique/indéfini. Cf http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?45;s=3726743910;r=5;nat=;sol=1; B. [Peut prendre une valeur indéterm. ou indéf.]

Comment: @guillaume31 Oui, un *tu* peut très bien être générique mais c'est le futur qui lui fait perdre ici cette valeur.

Comment: @jlliagre oui, ceci dit la phrase d'origine en anglais peut très bien être un présent de généralité. Dans ce cadre il me semble important de noter que l'usage de "tu" est possible, avec les bémols nécessaires quant au registre de langage.

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement la formulation au futur est moins générique.

Comment: @guillaume31 Je suis bien d'accord, je l'avais d'ailleurs repris dans ma réponse.